# How many shards per node?

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

How can I get information how many shards exists per node with specific id? I trying to find this information on the official documentation. But can't. One of the possible scenario it is get information about shards by this request and grouping by nodes:

```
GET /_cat/shards&v=true

index                      shard prirep state       docs store ip         node
people                     0     p      STARTED        1 4.4kb 172.17.0.2  1
blog                       0     p      STARTED        1 4.8kb 172.17.0.2  2
micrometer-metrics-2021-05 0     p      STARTED    14368   1mb 172.17.0.2  3
```

If you have any idea or thought please share with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `_cat/allocation` API

```
GET /_cat/allocation/1?v
```

And you'll get the number of shards for the specified node:

```
shards disk.indices disk.used disk.avail disk.total disk.percent host       ip         node
   121        1.3tb     1.3tb    466.4gb      1.8tb           74 10.x.y.z   10.x.y.z   1
```

Comment: Can I get how many shards belong to specific node without specify node id? 
GET /_cat/allocation - is it correct. I think it should show all nodes and how many shards belong to each of them, if I am rigth?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, if you leave out the node id, then you get the shard count for each node