# How many shards and max heap size per node?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I get information about about how many shards in the one specific node and what max size of heap in this node by one request to the Elasticsearch. I know how to get information about heap per node

```
GET _cat/nodes?h=heap*&v=true

heap.current heap.percent heap.max
287.4mb            6    4.3gb
```

Should I do 2 requests: one by getting how many shards per node, and another what heap.max size per node?
I trying to find this in the documentation, but without success:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-nodes.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-shards.html

But, maybe I something missed.

Comment: Regarding shards per node, see my answer in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67717956/how-many-shards-per-node)

Comment: Thank you. But it is not full answer on this question. Is it possible to get all this info by one request? Or should I do 2 separate requests to the elasticsearch?

Comment: Two separate requests, because the info comes from two different endpoints

Comment: Ok, I got it. But it is inconvenient.